# SceneKit: cannot add SCNReferenceNode programmatically though works in Xcode Scene Editor

Tags: xcode, scenekit, scnnode

Adding a SCNReferenceNode works when done from the Xcode Scene Editor. When done programmatically with the code below, however, nothing appears in the scene.

`filePath` contains a valid path as proven by the `print` statement as well as stepping through the code.

Help?

```
    if let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("RefTest", ofType: "scn", inDirectory: "TestScene.scnassets") {
        let referenceURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            let referenceNode = SCNReferenceNode(URL: referenceURL)
            scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(referenceNode!)
            print(referenceNode)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class docs claim that the loading policy instructs the `SCNReferenceNode` to load immediately by default:

> When the reference node loads its content (either automatically,
>   according to the loadingPolicy property, or when you call the load
>   method), SceneKit loads the referenced scene file. All children of the
>   scene file’s root node become children of the reference node.

However, this doesn't seem to happen by default. You must invoke the `load` function like so:

```
let referenceNode = SCNReferenceNode(URL: referenceURL
referenceNode.load()
```

Alternatively, perhaps you could play with the `loadingPolicy` property as well, but invoking the `load` function definitely works.