# How can I load multiple objects in SceneKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I've made a scn file called arrowsign.scn which contains a arrow like the picture below:
[image]

I wrote a piece of code to load the arrow object:

```
SCNNode *node = [SCNNode node];
SCNNode *a[10];
for (int i = 0;i<10;i++){
    a[i] = [scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"arrowsign" recursively:NO];//just one arrow in arrowsign.scn
    a[i].scale = SCNVector3Make(0.15f, 0.15f, 0.15f);
    a[i].position = SCNVector3Make(1+i, 0, 0);
    [node addChildNode:a[i]];
}
[scene.rootNode addChildNode:node];
```

Ideally there will be a row of arrows displaying in the screen. However, there is just one arrow displaying. How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply clone node

```
let sphereNode2 = sphereNode.clone()
sphereNode2.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: -20)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode2)
```

Comment: SCNNode *sign = [scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"arrowsign" recursively:YES];
    
    sign.scale = SCNVector3Make(0.15f, 0.15f, 0.15f);
    sign.position = SCNVector3Make(1, 0, 0);
    
    SCNNode *parentNode = [SCNNode node];
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        SCNNode *node = [sign clone];
        node.position = SCNVector3Make(1+i, 0, 0);
        [parentNode addChildNode:node];
    }
    [scene.rootNode addChildNode:parentNode];
Still one arrow displays...

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating new SCNNode instances, create [SCNReferenceNode](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnreferencenode) instances in order to load your .scn file into them.

Comment: I did SCNReferenceNode *a[10] but there is still just one arrow displaying.

Comment: Actually I am not sure how can I load my .scn file into SCNReferenceNode. Maybe this cause the "one arrow" problem.

Comment: Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39029865/scenekit-cannot-add-scnreferencenode-programmatically-though-works-in-xcode-sce)